# Convert Column Values to Columns and other Values Become that New Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and would like to transform the dataframe that the values in one column become new columns with the values from another column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3'],
               'name': ['Andi','Andy','Ben','Ben','Benjamin','Charlie','Charlie','Charlie','Charles'],
               'event': ['Basket','Basket','Basket','Soccer','Soccer','Basket','Basket','Soccer','Basket'],
               'reg_num': ['435','436','123','341','231','223','115','432','67']
               })
```

The result I expected is

```
                     Basket        Soccer
id Name
 1 Andi, Andy        435,436   
 2 Ben, Benjamin     123           231,341
 3 Charlie,Charles   223,115,67    432
```

I try to group by

`df2 = df.reset_index().groupby(['id','name','event'])['reg_num'].aggregate('first').unstack()`

but id doesn't merge the name or reg number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with add level of MultiIndex by aggregate `join` for unique pairs by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(['id','name']).groupby('id')['name'].agg(','.join)
print (s)
id
1          Andi,Andy
2       Ben,Benjamin
3    Charlie,Charles
Name: name, dtype: object

df2 = (df.pivot_table(index='id', 
                      columns='event', 
                      values='reg_num', 
                      aggfunc=','.join, 
                      fill_value='')
          .assign(Name=s)
          .set_index('Name', append=True))
print (df2)
event                   Basket   Soccer
id Name                                
1  Andi,Andy           435,436         
2  Ben,Benjamin            123  341,231
3  Charlie,Charles  223,115,67      432
```